# Solving for two variables in a vector problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm working through some vector problems in a book of problems I found online ([here](http://linear.ups.edu/version3/pdf/fcla-draft-solutions.pdf), see problem C15 on page 28). The problem I'm working on is

> Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that solve the vector equation.
>
> $\alpha \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix} + \beta \begin{bmatrix} 1\\3\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\0\\ \end{bmatrix}$

I did
$$\alpha \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix} + \beta \begin{bmatrix} 1\\3\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \alpha \\ \alpha\\ \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \beta\\3\beta\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2\alpha+\beta\\3\beta+\alpha\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$2\alpha+\beta=5$$
$$3\beta+\alpha=0$$
$$-3\beta+5=\alpha$$
$$2(-3\beta+5)+\beta=5$$
$$\beta=-1$$
$$-3(-1)+5=\alpha$$
$$8=a$$

I checked my answer, and I got $\beta$ right but it shows $\alpha$ as 3. The work it shows gives the same system of equations, but it solves them as follows:

> which we can solve by row-reducing the augmented matrix of the system,
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} 2&1&5\\1&3&0\\ \end{bmatrix} \overset{\text{RREF}}{\to} \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&3\\0&1&-1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ [Please note there should be a box around the two ones in the second matrix; I didn't know how to do that.]
>
> Thus, the only solution is $\alpha=3, \beta=-1$.

I am somewhat (okay, really) new to this, so I don't really understand what is wrong with my method or how how their method works. Any explanation would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does $-3\beta+5=\alpha$ come from?
Your system is
$$2\alpha+\beta=5,\quad 3\beta+\alpha=0.$$
From the second one, we get $\alpha=-3\beta$.then from the first one we obtain
$$2(-3\beta)+\beta=5\implies \beta=-1$$
and finally $\alpha=-3\beta=-3(-1)=3$.

P.S. In the solution on your book, the system is transformed into equivalent ones by replacing one equation with sum of that equation with a multiple of the other one. See Reduced Row-Echelon Form in your pdf. 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2&1&5\\1&3&0\\ \end{bmatrix} \overset{}{\to} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&5\\1&3&0\\ \end{bmatrix}
\overset{}{\to} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&5\\0&5&-5\\ \end{bmatrix}\\
\overset{}{\to} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&5\\0&1&-1\\ \end{bmatrix}
\overset{}{\to} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&3\\0&1&-1\\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @heather See my P.S.